# What kind of object is this?

Tags: php, python, json, object, format

I'm trying to load this object in python or PHP, but I'm now trying to know if there are libraries that are already written so that I don't parse the document myself.

```
variable = [["1","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],
["2","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],
["3","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"],
["4","arbitrary string","another arbitrary string"]];
another_variable = "arbitrary string";
```

Any hints will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: That's legitimate python code as-is.

Comment: Is there a way to load it into variables so that I can manipulate it?

Comment: looks like a flattened json object.

Comment: use something like `another_variable=json.loads(variable)` be sure to `import json`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?  as mgilson said, thats python code as is.

Comment: When I did json = urllib2.urlopen(url).read() the whole thing was read as a string. I was looking for something like: json["variable"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a lot like JSON. PHP has some built-in functions to handle it - json_decode, for instance: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php.

It looks like Python also has a JSON library built-in: http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html (the same library is available in Python 2 as well, if you're still using the "older" version).

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, hit the green check next to it to "accept" it. Otherwise, let me know if you need more information and I'll try to improve my answer. :)

Comment: When I did json = urllib2.urlopen(url).read() the whole thing was read as a string. I was looking for something like: json["variable"]

Comment: What you need to do is retrieve the JSON data as a string (via urlopen().read() for instance), and then use the JSON library to convert it to a variable. In particular, try json.loads(myVariable).

Answer (score 0):

That is a JSON encoded string, representing an array of arrays.

You can make it a PHP native element using :

```
$var = json_decode($variable);
```

Do note that `json_decode()` is build-in to PHP after 5.2 only. Otherwise you'll have to get it from PEAR.